# How to draw a circle with equidistant points by using LaTeX

Tags: latex

How to draw a circle  with equidistant points and a chord connecting the equidistant? For example,a circle with 4 equidistant point.

Comment: Draw a circle with 6 equidistant points ,labeled $1,\cdots,6$ and then conentect point1,point2,point3.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3944802/modular-arithmetic-on-node-names-in-tikz

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with TikZ. We can define a command `\equic` that takes as input the radius (optional, by default `1 cm`) and the number of points:

```
\newcommand{\equic}[2][1 cm]{
  \draw (0,0) circle (#1);
  \foreach \i in {1,...,#2} {
    \coordinate (N\i) at (\i*360/#2:#1);
    \fill[black] (N\i) circle (0.05 cm) node[anchor=west]{$\i$};
  }
  \draw (N#2) -- (N1);
  \foreach \i in {2,...,#2} {
    \pgfmathparse{\i-1}
    \edef\j{\pgfmathresult}
    \draw (N\i) -- (N\j);
  }
}
```

Now a standalone `.tex` file to test this command is the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\equic}[2][1 cm]{
  \draw (0,0) circle (#1);
  \foreach \i in {1,...,#2} {
    \coordinate (N\i) at (\i*360/#2:#1);
    \fill[black] (N\i) circle (0.05 cm) node[anchor=west]{$\i$};
  }
  \draw (N#2) -- (N1);
  \foreach \i in {2,...,#2} {
    \pgfmathparse{\i-1}
    \edef\j{\pgfmathresult}
    \draw (N\i) -- (N\j);
  }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\equic[5 cm]{6}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Which produces:

[image: result of the LaTeX command]

**EDIT** (based on your comment)

1. You can make the numbers clockwise by placing a minus at the coordinate definition:

   ```
   \coordinate (N\i) at (-\i*360/#2:#1);
   ```
2. You can put the numbers *outside* the circle by first calculating a radius that is a bit larger than the one of the circle (here `\oc` and an additional 0.25 cm):

   ```
   \pgfmathparse{#1/1 cm+0.25};
   \edef\oc{\pgfmathresult cm};
   ```
3. The query defines a set of coordinates `(N1)`, `(N2)` ... `(Nn)`. You can add instructions to your TikZ image like:

   ```
   \draw (N1) -- (N2) -- (N3) -- (N1);
   ```

   To draw lines from `(N1)` to `(N2)`, `(N2)` to `(N3)`, etc.
4. If you do not want to draw lines between all equidistant points, you can remove the second `\draw` statement and `\foreach` loop.

Putting it all together a new version of the file would be:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\equic}[2][1 cm]{
\draw (0,0) circle (#1);
\pgfmathparse{#1/1 cm+0.25};
\edef\oc{\pgfmathresult cm};
  \foreach \i in {1,...,#2} {
    \coordinate (N\i) at (-\i*360/#2:#1);
    \fill[black] (N\i) circle (0.05 cm);
    \draw (-\i*360/#2:\oc) node{$\i$};
  }
  \draw (N#2) -- (N1);
  \foreach \i in {2,...,#2} {
    \pgfmathparse{\i-1}
    \edef\j{\pgfmathresult}
    \draw (N\i) -- (N\j);
  }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\equic[5 cm]{6}
\draw (N1) -- (N2) -- (N3) -- (N1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The new output looks like:

[image: image showing equidistant points outside the circle]

**EDIT 2:**

You can define intermediate equidistant points using the following code:

```
\newcommand{\equic}[2][1 cm]{
\draw (0,0) circle (#1);
\pgfmathparse{#1/1 cm+0.25};
\edef\oc{\pgfmathresult cm};
  \foreach \i in {1,...,#2} {
    \coordinate (N\i) at (-\i*360/#2:#1);
    \coordinate (NB\i) at (-\i*360/#2-180/#2:#1);
    \fill[black] (N\i) circle (0.05 cm);
    \fill[black] (NB\i) circle (0.05 cm);
    \draw (-\i*360/#2:\oc) node{$\i$};
    \draw (-\i*360/#2-180/#2:\oc) node{$\bar{\i}$};
  }
}
```

Now the code produces two sets of points: the original `(N1)`, `(N2)`,...,`(Nn)`, and a new set of points: `(NB1)`, `(NB2)`,...,`(NBn)` (the `B` stands for bar), which are placed interleaved. Now you can again provide drawing commands yourself, like:

```
\draw (N1) -- (N2) -- (N3) -- (N1);
\draw (NB4) -- (NB5);
```

This produces the following image:

[image: circle with 12 equidistant points]

Full code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\equic}[2][1 cm]{
\draw (0,0) circle (#1);
\pgfmathparse{#1/1 cm+0.25};
\edef\oc{\pgfmathresult cm};
  \foreach \i in {1,...,#2} {
    \coordinate (N\i) at (-\i*360/#2:#1);
    \coordinate (NB\i) at (-\i*360/#2-180/#2:#1);
    \fill[black] (N\i) circle (0.05 cm);
    \fill[black] (NB\i) circle (0.05 cm);
    \draw (-\i*360/#2:\oc) node{$\i$};
    \draw (-\i*360/#2-180/#2:\oc) node{$\bar{\i}$};
  }
}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\equic[5 cm]{6}
\draw (N1) -- (N2) -- (N3) -- (N1);
\draw (NB4) -- (NB5);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I have several  questions.1.how can i put the number1,2,3,4,5,6outside the circle.2,how to arrange the number in clockwise direction..3.how to connect {1,2},{2,3}{1,3},@Willem Van Onsem

Comment: I'm new at using LaTex,would you mind answering my last question? I want to add another six points $\bar{1} \cdots,\bar{1} $ , $\bar{1}$ lies in the midpoint of arc(1,2),$\bar{2}$ lies in the midpoint of arc(2,3),etc.and connect $\bar{1},\bar{2}$ by dashed line.How to rewrite the code ?@Willem Van Onsem

Comment: Can you be a bit more formal: what dou mean with *midpoint of arc(1,2)*?

Comment: $\bar{1} is the  midpoint of arc(1,2) maens $\bar{1} is also the equidistant point.I shoul say there are 12  equidistant points ,which labeled by $1,\bar{1},2,\bar{2},\cdots,6,\bar{6}$ in clockwise direction.and then connect {1,2},{2,3}{1,3},conennect {\bar{4},\bar{5}}.Actually ,I want to draw a picture to explain the kreweras complement map.@Willem Van Onsem

Comment: @crazie: had some urgent work, so sorry for the delay. Is the edited answer the one you are looking for?