# How to draw a circle by using LaTeX

Tags: latex

I want to draw a circle with 6 equidistant points in Latex, labeled `1,...,6` and then connect point 1, point 2, point 3... Does anyone know how to draw it? Thanks!

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3944802/modular-arithmetic-on-node-names-in-tikz

Answer (score 3):

You can make use of [the `tikz` library](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jaaW3.png)

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    % equidistant points and arc
    \foreach \x [count=\p] in {0,...,11} {
        \node[shape=circle,fill=black, scale=0.5] (\p) at (-\x*30:2) {};};
    \foreach \x [count=\p] in {0,...,5} {
        \draw (-\x*60:2.4) node {\p};
        \draw (-30-\x*60:2.4) node {$\bar{\p}$};}; 
    \draw (1) arc (0:360:2);
    \draw[dashed] (1) -- (3) -- (5) -- (1);
    % axes
    \draw [dotted, gray] (-2.6,0) -- (2.6,0);
    \draw [dotted, gray] (0,-2.15) -- (0,2.15);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Circle]

Comment: I mean connect 1,2 by a segment .If i want to add $\bar{1}$ between 1 and 2  ,how to write the code?

Comment: yes,and I want to add points $bar{1}$ in the arc(1,2),$bar{2}$in the arc (2,3),etc

Comment: NO,I mean connecting 1 and 2 to be a chord of the circle ...make123 be a triangle..

Comment: OK,I rewrie the question. I Want to draw a circle with 12 equidistant points .in clockwise direction and lable the equidistant points by $1,\bar{1},2,\bar{2},3,\bar{3},\cdots,6,\bar{6},the last step ,I want to connect 1 and 2,1 and 3 ,2 and 3 whcih make 12 ,13,23,be a chord of the circle

Comment: Yes,the full circle to be solid.

Comment: Amazing!Thank you very much.